# Not able to click on Button JavaFX

Tags: java, button, javafx

I am creating a simple JavaFX based game and when I add a Button to my Pane and try to perform some action on it by clicking the mouse button while hovering over the button nothing happens - as if it is disabled but still visible.

```
private class Game extends Parent  {
   public Game() {

            private Button newGameButton;
            private Scene secondScene;
            private Stage secondStage;
            private Pane pane;
            VBox menu = new VBox(15);
            VBox highScore = new VBox(15);

            menu.setTranslateX(280);
            menu.setTranslateY(250);

            highScore.setTranslateX(100);
            highScore.setTranslateY(200);

            try {
                onLoad();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            newGameButton = new MenuButtonView("New Game");
            newGameButton.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {

                pane = new Pane();
                secondScene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);
                secondStage = new Stage();
                secondStage.setScene(secondScene);

                secondStage.show();

                scoreAndCrackView();
                mickeyView();
            });
 
public void mickeyView(){

            private Button leftDownRedButton;
            leftDownRedButton = new Button();
            rightDownRedButton.setTranslateX(640);
            rightDownRedButton.setTranslateY(560);
            
            pane.getChildren().add(rightDownRedButton);
            leftDownRedButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Clicked");
                }
            });



public void scoreAndCrackView()
    {
        vertBox = new VBox();
        vertBox.setPrefSize(800, 100); // this one was causing issue, previously: vertBox.setPrefSize(800, 600)

        vertBox.getChildren().addAll(scoreLabel,crackLabel);
        pane.getChildren().add(vertBox);

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Btw I found the cause of the error - as you guys suggested something was covering my buttons and more precisely the VBox in another method which was set to the whole screen. After changing the values and minimizing prefWidth and prefHeight I can click on the buttons. Lesson for the future to set the Box only for the required area.

Comment: What is the `MenuButtonView` class?

Comment: @VGR just added it, please take a look. In general - button design

Comment: My guess is that the Rectangle and Text are intercepting the mouse event.  Try adding `buttonText.setMouseTransparent(true);` and `buttonRectangle.setMouseTransparent(true);`.

Comment: [mcve] please.. mind the __M__!

Comment: I don't understand why you would do a Button this way.  The Button class itself is completely styleable, and you can put anything you want into Button.setGraphic().  Then you get exactly the look you want but it's still a Button and will behave properly.

Comment: @DaveB because I use this private class for many buttons and don't want to duplicate code. Btw I found the cause of the error - as VGR suggested something was covering my buttons and more precisely the VBox which was set to the whole screen. After changing the values and minimizing prefWidth and prefHeight I can click on the buttons. Lesson for the future to set the Box only for the required area